# Converting base64 string to byte array using Json Serializable class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am sending form data through **ajax** in **JSON** format and in model I have `byte[]` type variable in my model class

Image will **BASE64** format

```
var profileImage = $('#profileImage').attr('src');
```

Ajax call:

```
$
            .ajax({
                type : 'PUT',
                url : baseUrl + "/restApi/UpdateUser",
                data : JSON
                        .stringify({
                             "fname" : fname,
                             "lname" : lname,
                             "password" : password,
                             "email" : email,
                             "profileImage":profileImage
                        }),
                success: function(){

                },

                error : function(e){
                    ////////////console.log(e);
                },
                dataType : "json",
                contentType : "application/json"
            });
```

In model class I used Serialization to convert my Base64 string to byte array since json value will be in string.

This is my GreenBusUser model class

```
@Lob
@Column(name="profile_picture")
@JsonDeserialize(using = StringtoByteArray.class)
private byte[] profileImage= null;

public byte[] getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(byte[] profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

class StringtoByteArray extends JsonDeserializer<byte []> {

    @Override
    public byte[] deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return (Base64.getEncoder().encode(jsonParser.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    }
}
```

when I print my log to get the picture `greenbususer.getProfileImage();`

I am getting some weird value :

> **[B@12db4fbd**

I dont know what is causing the problem and it also not saved in my postgresql db. Please resolve.

**UPDATE:**

I have updated some code

```
return (Base64.getDecoder().decode(jsonParser.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

As Paul Warren said I need to deserialize then I should decode there I did it but received error.

[image: Error Log]

**Partially RESOLVED:**

It's weird and if somebody could answer what happened here then I will accept his/her answer and also will help many to shed some light on it.

Instead of decoding(like Timur told) the base64 string and calling getBytes method on it I have directly called getBytes method on base64 string. Like this:

```
return (jsonParser.getText().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

But I received that column **profile_image** is of type **bytea** and expression is of type **bigint**. Rewrite or cast the expression(something like that).

When I finally remove `@Lob` expression it worked without causing any problem please take a look.

This is my db where image binary data got inserted.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The value that you got is "toString" representation of byte array. It is not the content of the array. For debug purpose you can just write byte array to file and verify image with standard tools.

```
Files.write(Paths.get("./debug_image.png"), greenBusUser.getProfileImage());
```

Also it seems like you need to fix your "deserialize" method and replace **encoding** (byte[] -> Base64) by **decoding** (Base64 -> byte[]).. I belive it should be like following:

```
return Base64.getDecoder().decode(jsonParser.getText());
```

Comment: Timur I have tried what you told but I am getting Illegal base64 character at my User class itself

Comment: I have updated my code like you have to told me and also the error I received while trying that piece of code please take a look.

In writing the image into the file I am getting broken or empty or unsupported image

Comment: Mohammand, please clarify what data you send as `profileImage` field in the _PUT_ request? Is it BASE64 format?

Comment: Timur, I resolved the problem please take a look and comment on it please what happened and if want to discuss we can come to live chatting to discuss the problem and why decoder wasn't working also what's the deal with this @Lob annotation

Comment: Timue the data I received after doing that is not image data but some random binary data I dont know what happened can we discuss live so that I can show you what I received at my end. Please help if possible